# Software / OS for a VPS company that supports server clusters with load balancing

Tags: operating-system, cluster-computing, load-balancing, vps

Just wondering if there is any OS that will automatically load balance virtual machines across my server cluster ?

Answer (score 0):

Not an OS but you can look into: http://haproxy.1wt.eu/